# How to use generic type for interface - TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the two interfaces shown below:

```
export interface TestInterface<T> {
  obj: T;
  text: string;
}

export type anotherType = 'value1' | 'value2';
export interface TestInterfaceTwo {
  first: string;
  second: anotherType;
  third: string;
}
```

Which is used in another file as

```
markValue: TestInterface<TestInterfaceTwo>[] = [
    { obj: { first: 'abc', second: 'def', third: 'ghi' }, text: 'I exist' },
    { obj: { first: 'jkl', second: 'mno', third: 'pqr' }, text: 'I dont exist'  }
  ];
```

How can I avoid using `<T>` and still use the generic type for the `TestInterface<T>`?

Comment: How is that supposed to work? How is TypeScript supposed to magically guess what `T` is?

Comment: Are you looking for the compiler to *infer* `TestInterfactTwo`, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#32794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794)?  If so, there's no direct support for this and you'd need to use a helper function as a workaround, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM13bm).  But your `second` property is weird here; surely `markValue` is not valid because `second` is `"def"` and `"mno"`.  And if you care about something like `'value1' | 'value2'` as opposed to `string` then I don't see why you wouldn't *want* to specify `TestInterfaceTwo` in there?

Comment: Let me know if I'm close to understanding this (and mention @jcalz if you reply) and what,  if anything, you want to see here.

Comment: @jcalz I have updated the code above what I meant wrt to the value1 | value 2

Comment: That didn't change anything, sorry. I guess you didn't understand, let me try again.  Why did you write `"def"` and `"mno"` in your example?  Are you *intentionally* writing invalid values?  If so, why?  If not, is it a typo or something?

Comment: @jcalz yeah those are just to represent that they are all strings which we are using from TestInterfaceTwo

Comment: I don't understand, sorry.  In what way does `"def"` and `"mno"` represent `"value1"` or `"value2"`?  Is it a metaphor?  Poetic license?  In order to help those of us not able to see the figurative meaning here, could you provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE?  Right now your example gives me errors with `"def"` and `"mno"`.  Are those errors relevant to the question?  If not, then I would recommend resolving them so that they don't distract us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give T the default value of any

```
export interface TestInterface<T = any> {
  obj: T;
  text: string;
}
```